# Unable to pass arguments to bash - jenkins password parameter

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins-pipeline, arguments

I am trying to pass some arguments to my bash file. However, all except one i.e. the password parameter is not getting passed properly.

Below is the pipeline script.

```
    parameters {
        string(name: 'CF_API_HOST', defaultValue: '', description: 'Provide CF API Host')
        string(name: 'CF_LOGIN_HOST', defaultValue: '', description: 'Provide CF Login Host')
        string(name: 'CF_ORG', defaultValue: '', description: 'Provide CF Organization')
        string(name: 'CF_SPACE', defaultValue: '', description: 'Provide CF Space')
        string(name: 'ENV', defaultValue: '', description: 'Provide Environment')
        string(name: 'AAPRDS_FLAG', defaultValue: '', description: 'Provide type of RDS deployment')
        string(name: 'AAPVAULT_FLAG', defaultValue: '', description: 'Provide type of VAULT deployment')
        string(name: 'AAPREDIS_FLAG', defaultValue: '', description: 'Provide type of REDIS deployment')
        string(name: 'AAPUPS_FLAG', defaultValue: '', description: 'Provide type of UPS deployment')
        string(name: 'AAPAPPS_FLAG', defaultValue: '', description: 'Provide type of APPS deployment')
        string(name: 'AAPVERSION', defaultValue: '', description: 'Provide version of AAP')
        string(name: 'AAPROUTE_FLAG', defaultValue: '', description: 'Provide keyword of CF Route change')
        string(name: 'AAPSTOPAPPS_FLAG', defaultValue: '', description: 'Provide keyword for stopping apps')
        string(name: 'BUILD_REPORT_EMAIL_TO', defaultValue: '', description: 'Provide Email of Build Report Recipient')
        string(name: 'CF_USN', defaultValue: '', description: 'Cloudfoundry credentials')
        password(name: 'CF_PWD', defaultValue: '', description: 'Cloudfoundry credentials')
    }
    agent { docker { image 'ubuntu:20.04' 
                     args '-u root:sudo -e TERM=xterm' 
    } }
    stages {
        stage ('PreDeployment') {
        
                steps {
                    sh '''
                    cd $WORKSPACE/appDeploy/aap
                    DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get update -y && apt install curl wget -y
                    apt-get install python3 python3-pip -y
                    wget -q -O - https://packages.cloudfoundry.org/debian/cli.cloudfoundry.org.key | apt-key add -
                    echo "deb https://packages.cloudfoundry.org/debian stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cloudfoundry-cli.list
                    apt-get update -y
                    apt-get install cf7-cli -y
                    DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y apt-transport-https software-properties-common -y
                    wget -q https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.04/packages-microsoft-prod.deb
                    dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb
                    apt-get update -y
                    add-apt-repository universe
                    apt-get install -y powershell
                    '''
                }
            }
        stage ('Deployment') {
         steps {
            dir ("$WORKSPACE/appDeploy/aap"){
                
                    sh 'chmod +x aapdeploy.sh'
                    sh "./aapdeploy.sh \"${params.ENV}\" \"${params.AAPRDS_FLAG}\" \"${params.AAPVAULT_FLAG}\" \"${params.AAPREDIS_FLAG}\" \"${params.AAPUPS_FLAG}\" \"${AAPAPPS_FLAG}\" \"${params.AAPVERSION}\" \"${params.AAPROUTE_FLAG}\" \"${params.AAPSTOPAPPS_FLAG}\" \"${params.CF_USN}\" \"${params.CF_PWD}\" \"${params.CF_API_HOST}\" \"${params.CF_LOGIN_HOST}\" \"${params.CF_ORG}\" \"${params.CF_SPACE}\""
            }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The issue occurs with the CF_PWD parameter. It doesn't accept the password properly and ends with failed login attempt through the bash script.

Jenkins log :

```
+ ./aapdeploy.sh prestg NOCHANGE NOCHANGE NOCHANGE NOCHANGE DEPLOY 4.002 NOCHANGE NOCHANGE opsuser 2 https://api.cf.test.com login.cf.test.com client UAT
```

As per jenkins logs , the username is being passed correctly, but for the password it always shows as '2'.
Can't understand where i am going wrong. Can someone please point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do not pass passwords in arguments. This is a security bug. Program arguments are public on Unix systems.

Comment: Even if i use withCredentials () in pipeline I observe the same scenario.

Comment: @ceving, thanks for the insight, actually that helped. I didn't have to pass it as arguments at all.

Answer (score 0):

No need to pass arguments. Ignorance on my part. Add withCredentials()in pipeline and credentials are available within the script.